# how to find number of active users for say 1 day,2 days, 3 days.....postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, windowing, partition-by

A distribution of # days active within a week: I am trying to find how many members are active for 1 day, 2days, 3days,…7days during a specific week 3/1-3/7.

Is there any way to use aggregate function on top of partition by?
If not what can be used to achieve this?

```
select distinct memberID,count(date) over(partition by memberID) as no_of_days_active
from visitor
where date between '"2019-01-01 00:00:00"' and '"2019-01-07 00:00:00"'
order by no_of_days_active
```

result should look something like this

```
#Days Active    Count
1           20
2           32
3           678
4           34
5           3
6           678
7           2345
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want two levels of aggregation to count the number of days during the week:

```
select num_days_active, count(*) as num_members
from (select memberID, count(distinct date::date) as num_days_active
      from visitor
      where date >= '2019-01-01'::date and 
            date < '2019-01-08'::date
      group by memberID
     ) v
group by num_days_active
order by num_days_active;
```

Note that I changed the date comparisons.  If you have a time component, then `between` does not work.  And, because you included time in the constant, I added an explicit conversion to date for the `count(distinct)`.  That might not be necessary, if `date` is really a date with no time component.

Comment: Thank you Gordan. Added a group by within the subquery and getting the results correctly.                                                                                                          
select num_days_active, count(*) as num_members
from (select memberID, count(distinct date::date) as num_days_active
          from visitor
          where date >= '2019-01-01'::date and 
          date < '2019-01-08'::date
          group by memberID) v
group by num_days_active
order by num_days_active

Answer (score 0):

Piggybacking off of @Gordon's answer, I personally like using a `with` statement for the subqueries:

```sql
with dat as (
    select distinct
        memberID,
        count(date) over(partition by memberID) as no_of_days_active
    from visitor
    where 1=1
        and date between '2019-01-01'::date and '2019-01-07'::date
    order by no_of_days_active
)

select 
    no_of_days_active, 
    count(no_of_days_active) no_of_days_active_cnt
from dat
group by no_of_days_active
order by no_of_days_active
```